# How and when the Linux kernel calls sysctl_init() in kernel 3.14.17?

Tags: linux-kernel

The version of my linux kernel is 3.14.17.

When it's in linux-2.6.20, it call `sysctl_init()` during `do_basic_setup()` which is in `init/main.c`.

On the new version, I can't find how the kernel calls it?

Comment: did you browse the source code tree?

Comment: I only search the keyword in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/, the only it has is in sysctl.c, maybe it be called in another name. I don't understand the source code tree you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sysctl_init is called by
    proc_sys_init, by
        proc_root_init, by
            start_kernel
```

Comment: It's very useful! Could you tell me how to find this quickly?

Comment: @zxy_snow you may start from reading this link http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html